# How to configure screen brightness when not using a laptop

Tags: screen, brightness

For a *way* too strange reason, my TV (which I'm using with a Dell Inspiron 1145 laptop running Ubuntu 11.10) does not allow me to do a fine-grained brightness configuration. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to configure this using Ubuntu by itself.

I've found a lot of articles/forum posts describing how to this, but all the solutions were related to notebooks.

Is there a way to configure my Tv/Monitor brightness without using its own controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used to use xgamma, from terminal:

```
myuser@mypc:~$ xgamma -gamma 0.8
```

I suppose the default gamma value is 1.0 (you can set greater values to brighter...). As far as I remember, the value is reset when you start a new session.

Comment: Hey, if you're using a NVIDIA's card and it is installed the NVIDIA X Server Settings, you're able to change the gamma (and contrast, and brightness) value through this graphical config software, in "X Server Color Correction" option.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using NVIDIA drivers. The xgamma approach worked. However, the image become a little bit weird for values < 0.6. Any tip on that?

Thank you very much, anyway :-)

Comment: You can test it by changing each color separately (Red, Green and Blue), have a look on xgamma manual (rgamma, ggamma and bgamma options). Maybe the weirdness go away after adjusting it. =)

And gamma correction is not the same of brightness and contrast, but I don't know a way of changing these properties yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the same as 12.04

System Settings -> Brightness and Lock

And adjust the slider.

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: In theory, you're right. But this only works for laptops' monitors.